# Keep the dropdown value selected after refresh of page

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I'm trying to select value, but when I refresh the page it resets the values.

```
<div class="clearfix mb-20">

    <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
    <label class="form-label"><?= __('Gender') ?></label>
    <select class="input" name="filter_gender">
    <option value="both" <?= $Schedule->get("filter_gender") == "both" ? "selected" : "" ?>><?= __("Both") ?></option>
    <option value="male" <?= $Schedule->get("filter_gender") == "male" ? "selected" : "" ?>><?= __("Male") ?></option>
    <option value="female" <?= $Schedule->get("filter_gender") == "female" ? "selected" : "" ?>><?= __("Female") ?></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Any way to get this fixed?

```
filter_gender: $form.find(":input[name='filter_gender']").val(),
```

How do I add gender here?

```
        $Schedule->set("user_id", $AuthUser->get("id"))
             ->set("account_id", $Account->get("id"))
             ->set("target", $target)
             ->set("speed", \Input::post("speed"))
             ->set("is_active", (bool)\Input::post("is_active"))
             ->set("daily_pause", $daily_pause)
             ->set("end_date", $end_date);
```

Comment: when the user selects the value save it into localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: How Do i Add Write Storage Commands for this code in PHP, I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: When you select something in your form (select option), you change the url and add the parameters. So using ‘onChange’ event on your form or form element you can change the url and add the param.

Example: `http://www.example.com?my_select_option=any_value`

Solution 2: Using cookies, set some cookies with a key ‘my_specific_form_filters’ and values an object with your selected form elements.

Example: `{my_select_option: “any_value”}`

Solution 3: Same logic as cookies applies for local storage where you can save data based on key value.

Solution 4: Save in PHP session based also on key value and retrieve when needed.